# Django Migration RunSQL Conditional on Database Type

Tags: django, django-orm, django-migrations, django-database

I am trying to use a `migrations.RunSQL` Django migration to run some arbitrary SQL code. I would like to run this migration for only certain db backends (for example only for postgres).

I would think [to use something like this](https://github.com/dcramer/django-uuidfield/blob/9bd27e96ede8cf770df60808f2c772c48ec73e74/uuidfield/fields.py#L121) but I don't see the DB connection info in the `Migration` class.

Answer (score 27):

Here is how I solved the problem since I couldn't get `RunSQL` to work inside `RunPython`. Thankfully, the `schema_editor` object has an [`execute()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/schema-editor/#execute).

```
def forwards(apps, schema_editor):
    if not schema_editor.connection.vendor.startswith('postgres'):
        logger.info('Database vendor: {}'.format(schema_editor.connection.vendor))
        logger.info('Skipping migration without attempting to ADD CONSTRAINT')
        return

    schema_editor.execute('ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint (my_field != \'NaN\';)')


def backwards(apps, schema_editor):
    if not schema_editor.connection.vendor.startswith('postgres'):
        logger.info('Database vendor: {}'.format(schema_editor.connection.vendor))
        logger.info('Skipping migration without attempting to DROP CONSTRAINT')
        return

    schema_editor.execute('ALTER TABLE my_table DROP CONSTRAINT my_constraint;')


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ...
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forwards, backwards, atomic=True)
    ]
```

Comment: This worked for me, except I need to have atomic=False

Comment: Be careful with `atomic=False`. If some actions succeed and others fail, your database could end up in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Django would refuse to run it for me otherwise.

Comment: The `atomic=False` has to be used at least on MySQL and Oracle, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/migration-operations/#runpython

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same need. I had to edit a migration that set the initial value of a sequence, which works on postgres but not sqlite. Here's how I wrapped the RunSQL inside a RunPython, following the documentation that Daniel linked to.

```
from django.db import migrations


def forwards(apps, schema_editor):
    if not schema_editor.connection.vendor == 'postgres':
        return
    migrations.RunSQL(
        "alter sequence api_consumer_id_seq restart with 1000500;")


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('api', '0043_auto_20160416_2313'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forwards),
    ]
```

Comment: My vendor string was `postgresql` and not `postgres` (in Django 1.10.6)

Comment: The problem with this is that `migrations.RunSQL()` returns an object. It doesn't actually execute any SQL until that object's `_run_sql()` method is called with certain parameters. See PaulMest's response for a solution that also uses the `migrations.RunPython()` method but executes SQL in a way that actually executes SQL.

Answer (score 6):

I solved a similar problem today -- needing to perform a migration to create a new model, but only for a postgres DB -- and I found this question. However, Matthew's answer did not help me. In fact, I'm not sure it works at all. That is because the line with `migrations.RunSQL(...)` does not actually *run* SQL; it *creates* a new object of type `RunSQL` which is a `Command`, and then immediately discards it.

Here's how I ended up solving the problem, in case anyone tries to search for "django conditional migration" in the future:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import django.contrib.postgres.fields
from django.db import migrations, models


class PostgresOnlyCreateModel(migrations.CreateModel):
    def database_forwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        if schema_editor.connection.vendor.startswith("postgres"):
            super(PostgresOnlyCreateModel, self).database_forwards(app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state)

    def database_backwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        if schema_editor.connection.vendor.startswith("postgres"):
            super(PostgresOnlyCreateModel, self).database_backwards(app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ...whatever...
    ]

    operations = [
        PostgresOnlyCreateModel(
            name='...whatever...',
            fields=[...whatever...],
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

That information is not provided in the Migration class, it is provided in the `schema_editor` attribute passed to a RunPython operation. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/writing-migrations/) for some examples on using this.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have the actual sql depend on db.connection.vendor:

```
from django.db import connection

CONCURRENTLY = "CONCURRENTLY" if connection.vendor == "postgres" else ""
SQL = f"CREATE INDEX {CONCURRENTLY}..."
```

At that point you can just use `migrations.RunSQL`, which is handy, particularly if you use the `state_operations` argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply migrations depending on app or model, I think the best solution is using [django database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate).

First define a database router class:

```py
from django.db import connections

class PgOnlyMigrateRouter:

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'pgonly_app' or model_name == 'pgonly_model':
            return connections[db].vendor.startswith("postgres")
        return None
```

Then in your setting.py file, add this line:

```py
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.PgOnlyMigrateRouter']
```

As you see, this works for all migrations in specified model or app, not just a single migration operation.